# Python (2.7): how to avoid imported modules to appear as part of my modules?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have written two modules m1.py and m2.py each of which uses various modules from the standard library.

For example

```
#m1.py
import sys
#.
#.
```

and

```
#m2.py
import os
#.
#.
```

What "bothers" me is that when I import in main.py the two modules m1.py and m2.py
I can use the functions defined in sys and os like this:

```
#main.py
print m1.sys.version
print m2.os.listdir()
```

Is this normal, or there is something I should consider when importing modules in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't need to worry about what is accessible in your namespace. Anyone who messes around with stuff that's not part of the module's documented API deserves whatever trouble they get. Python assumes that it's programmers are responsible adults.

The exception is when you specifically want to allow other code to use the otherwise discouraged `from mymodule import *` syntax. Then you want to limit what is public, so that you don't clutter up your importer's namespaces with your own internal stuff.

Here's how you can do that:

- Names that begin with an underscore (e.g. `_foo`) are assumed to be private, and won't be imported with `from mymodule import *`. This isn't "real" privacy, as anyone who does a normal import will still be able to access them via `mymodule._foo` (but they probably shouldn't!).
- If you want to make the modules you're importing private, use an `as` clause to give them a "private" name as described above. That is, use `import os as _os`.
- Or, rather than messing around with underscores, you can create an `__all__` variable that explicitly lists the module's public names. Only the names in the list will be imported with a `from mymodule import *` statement. Note that an `__all__` sequence is required in packages if you want the submodules to be importable via `from mypackage import *`. That's because Python can't trust the filesystem not to mess with the capitalization of the filenames the package contains.